Efficiently finding combinations from a CSV file to match a target sum
I'm working on a Python project where I need to find combinations of products from a CSV file that match a given target sum. Each product has a name and a price associated with it. I've implemented a solution using recursion and itertools, but it's not efficient, especially when dealing with larger datasets.
import csv
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

def read_products_from_csv(csv_file):
    products = {}
    with open(csv_file, 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        next(reader)  # Skip the header row
        for row in reader:
            product, price = row
            products[product] = float(price)
    return products

def find_combinations(products, target_amount):
    for r in range(1, len(products) + 1):
        for combination in combinations_with_replacement(products.items(), r):
            total_price = sum(price for _, price in combination)
            if total_price == target_amount:
                return combination
    return None

def main():
    csv_file = "products.csv"  # Replace with your CSV file path
    target_amount = float(input("Enter the sum amount: "))

    products = read_products_from_csv(csv_file)
    combination = find_combinations(products, target_amount)

    if combination:
        print("Combination found:")
        for product, price in combination:
            print(f"{product}: ${price}")
    else:
        print("No combination found.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


The issue with this code is that it's not efficient, especially for larger datasets. For example, when trying to find combinations for just 100 records, it takes a significant amount of time, potentially even days. I can't imagine how long it would take to process a CSV file with 100,000 records.
I'm looking for a more efficient approach to finding combinations from a CSV file that matches a target sum. Any suggestions or insights on how to improve the efficiency of my code would be greatly appreciated!

Do you feel that this is essentially "The knapsack problem"?

Do not tag this as dsa.  The dsa tag is for Digital Signature Algorithm.


Put a bound on max number of items to combine, perhaps K=3.
Use a SortedDict to map from price to product, so you can binary search for appropriate price that would complete the sum.
Adopt “The Price Is Right” comparisons, and be tolerant of small mismatch, perhaps an epsilon of a dollar or two.
Stop testing whether A + B == C when those are floating point prices. Convert everything to integer cents to avoid rounding issues. Otherwise details like whether .1 + .2 == .3 will cause you grief.
Use a knapsack solver library.

